# Don't Starve Together: Changing resources + Starting Variety, what do these settings mean?

Tags: dont-starve-together

In Don't Starve Together, when you're creating a new Map and want to customise the behaviour of the game, what do these two options do?

Starting resource variety: Classic | Default | Highly Random

Changing Resources: Default | None | Few | Medium | Many | Maximum

Comment: You should Test each option

Comment: What a 'useful' contribution...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Changing Resource is the different type like Berry Bushes and Juicy Berry Bushes, Twiggy Trees and Saplings, stuff like that, because in each world you can find an alternative resource so maybe it means that you can find more instead of sections you can find them in, but hey, its a guess.